# change font size of labels without knowing labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I would like to change the font size of the labels in this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
        geom_text(label=rownames(mtcars))
p
```

[image: mtcars plot]

**My problem: I do not know what the labels are.** (I stored a plot in which I used different `data.frame()`s to `add geom_text()`. I now only loaded the plot (`p` in this example), but do not want to also load the `data.frame()`s with which I created the labels).

As I do not know what the labels are, I cannot use this solution:

```
p + geom_text(label=rownames(mtcars), size=2)
```

(Another problem with this solution would be that I still needed to delete the original geom_text() with the larger font-size).

---

I can change the size of all text in the plot with this solution:

```
library(grid)    
grid.force()
grid.gedit("GRID.text", grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(fontsize=4.5))
```

However, now also my axes changed, which is not what I wanted.

---

I believe there are several options to achieve what I want, at least two of which should be fairly simply to implement:

1. Save the object from `grid.gedit()` to `p1` and then `p1 +  theme(text = element_text(size=2))`. My problem here: I do not know how to save the object from `grid.gedit()`. **This would be my preferred option.**
2. Go to the right viewport before applying `grid.gedit()`. I tried this, but still change both the labels (which I want) and the axes text (which I do not want).
3. Somehow extract the `data.frame` for the labels from the stored plot (`p` in this example) to apply the solution that I provided first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grid.gedit` command was close. You need to set up a `gPath` so that the edit command finds just those labels in the plot panel. `grid.ls(grid.force())` returns a hierarchy of grobs. Find the 'panel', then the 'text'. (Note: the 'g' in 'gedit' stands for 'grep = TRUE, global = TRUE')

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
        geom_text(label=rownames(mtcars))
p

library(grid)    
grid.ls(grid.force())   # Locate the path to the labels in the panel
grid.gedit(gPath("panel","GRID.text"), gp=gpar(fontsize=4.5))
```

If you prefer, with a few more lines of code, the plot object can be edited rather than editing on screen.

```
g = ggplotGrob(p)
g = editGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("panel", "GRID.text"), grep=TRUE, gp=gpar(fontsize=4.5))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect (/modify) the plot after building it,

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_text(label=rownames(mtcars))

g <- ggplot_build(p)
# original data is in str(g$plot$data)

# but it's easier to process the data for rendering
g[["data"]][[1]][["size"]] <- 5
g[["data"]][[1]][["colour"]] <- "red"

gg <- ggplot_gtable(g)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: + 1 for showing how ggplot stores the data that I thought I could not access. Decided to go for Sandy's solution in the end because I like the grid syntax for modifications, but that is a personal preference.